# Random data Repeating records in Query

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I select questions in random from database without repeating.

Also questions of different exams are in the same database.

I am using the following query.

```
$query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `quest` WHERE `eid`=$id ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $offset, $limit");
```

Comment: the rand you used should work properly, what's not working with it?

Comment: Add `DISTINCT` to your query and/or `GROUP BY`

Comment: What are the fields in the table, and could you also provide 2 or 3 lines from the table as well? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Distinct and RAND() will do the work :

```
$this->db->distinct()
        ->where('eid', intval($id))
        ->limit(intval($limit), intval($offset))
        ->order_by('RAND()')
        ->get('quest')
        ->result_array();
```